# Evaluate $ \lim \limits_{x\to \infty}12e^{(x/2)}-8e^{(x/3)}$

Tags: calculus

Evaluate $ \lim \limits_{x\to \infty}12e^{(x/2)}-8e^{(x/3)}$

---

I know the answer is $\infty$, however I am not finding an easy way to prove it.. Any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$12e^{x/2}-8e^{x/3}=4e^{x/3}\left(3e^{x/6}-2\right)$$

and since both factors in the right diverge to infinity that is the limit.

Comment: Oh can I use it in general ? $$\lim \limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)\cdot g(x) =\infty $$ if the limit of both functions is infinity is it ?

Comment: Or if one of the limits is non-zero and finite positive (negative) and the other one is $\;+\infty\;(-\infty)\;$